# "Empty collection literal requires an explicit type" error on Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a variable on my class:

```
var list = []
```

and I use it on a function of my class:

```
func chargeData (data: NSArray){
    list = data
}
```

It worked well on my project in `Swift 2.3` but when I have updated it to `XCode8` and `Swift3` it gives to me the following error:

> Empty collection literal requires an explicit type

so I have added a typecast to my list variable:

```
var list = [] as! NSArray
```

but it gives to me the following alert:

> Forced cast of 'NSArray' to same type has no effect

I know that an alert does not broke the application but I would like to solve this error in a proper way.

Did someone got the same error and solved it properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would have to do `var list:NSArray = []`. It's ok if you just replace it with another one. But it is not *mutable* itself, so `var list:NSMutableArray = []` would be better I suppose.

Comment: @EricAya What do you really mean with the fact that is not mutable itself? I know that mutable means that it can change its values but I am not really sure what do you mean with "mutable itself".

Comment: CodeDifferent explains it in their answer. var/let and NSArray/NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This error occurs since implicit conversions are abolished so you have to tell the compiler the explicit type (of the `ArrayLiteral` `[]`):

```
var list: NSArray = []
// or
var list = [] as NSArray
```

Answer (score 13):

The **Swift 5** *guided tour* is pretty explicit about creating empty arrays or dictionaries: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html#ID461 towards the end of the first section.

> To create an empty array or dictionary, use the initializer syntax.

```
let emptyArray = [String]()
let emptyDictionary = [String: Float]()
```

Answer (score 7):

Update swift 4 :

```
var array = [] as [String]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing ObjectiveC (`NSArray`) and Swift (`Array<T>`). Items inside an `NSArray` are assumed to be `NSObject` and its subclasses, while Swift has no clue what `T` is since the array is empty and hence type inference doesn't work.

If you declare it like this:

```
var data: NSArray = []
```

there will be a conflict since `var` means mutable in Swift, but `NSArray` is immutable in ObjC. You can get around that by changing it to `NSMutableArray`, which is a subclass of `NSArray`:

```
let data = NSMutableArray() // note that we don't need var here
                            // as NSMutableArray is already mutable
```

If you want to keep `data` as Swift's `Array`, give it a type:

```
var data = [MyDataModel]()
// or
var data = [AnyObject]()

// usage:
chargeData(data: data as NSArray)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Object: var urls = [String](); Caller: sm.urls.append("word!"); print(sm.urls[0]);